# Symfony2 MongoDB Order by reference

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, dql

**Situation**

I've a system where users register for learning when assigned to them. This learning then references sessions and modules but for the sake of this question they aren't so important.

Simplifed Data model (The // comments represent relationship annotation):

```
user
    id
    //ReferenceMany(
    //    targetDocument="UserModule",
    //    mappedBy="user",
    //    cascade={"persist"},
    //    orphanRemoval=true
    //)
    userModules

userModule
    id
    status
    // ReferenceOne(
    //    targetDocument="User"
    //)
    module

module
    id
    title
```

This report takes the form of an excel spreadsheet. To construct this, I start of getting all modules ordered by their reference so end up with x number of headings. E.g. M01, M02, etc.

At the same time, I create a Module "map" because in theory, a user muight not even have what would later be the current heading.

Once these headings and map are setup, I then start to loop over the users themselves and output the status of each module.

I then loop over the user modules and compare against the assigned user modules for every module that could be.

**Problem**

This approach is very resource intensive when cycling through a few hundred people and will become exponentially hungry as the number of modules increases.

I am finding that even though the users may initially have their userModule in correct order, it can quickly lose that order as they change. E.G The userModules array starts with M04 instead of M01.

**Question**

When cycling through the userModules for any given user, how can I maintain the order of modules. M01, M02, M03

**Attempt**

This is what lives in the UserRepository when i get the users, again simplified for the sake of the question

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->sort('userModules.module.id' => 'asc') // Tried many varieties of this
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Thank you in advance for reading this question

Comment: It might be better to use $Push to maintain order here https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort on update